# Angular: how to update route data of another component

Tags: angular, routes

One of the component gets its user account info via route like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
        this.accountDetails = data.accountDetails;
    });
}
```

Another component revises the user account info, and uses router.navigate() to redirect to the first component template HTML, but the user info is not shown updated - that's sure, since the route data is not updated.

How to update the first component's route data, so the user info can be updated in its template? I know observable could help like this example:

https://angular.io/guide/router

and its live demo: 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnogpayllep

But here in this example the data is actually not got from route, instead it's using an observable heroes$ and call service form ngInit directly:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
        return this.service.getHeroes();
    });
}
```

Looks like this is a little different to my situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're not supposed to pass data into the router. But if you do, it's supposed to be static :

> Represents the static data associated with a particular route

[*(From the documentation)*](https://angular.io/api/router/Data)

if you want to exchange data between two components, I advise you to [**use a sharing service**](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).